# Formula for finite power series

Tags: summation, power-series, geometric-series

Are there any formula for result of following power series?
$$0\leq q\leq 1$$
$$
\sum_{n=a}^b  q^n
$$

Answer (score 12):

Yes, consider the following manipulation:
$$
S = \sum_{n=a}^b q^n = q^a + q^{a+1} + \cdots + q^b = q^a + q(q^a + a^{a+1} + \cdots + q^{b-1}) = q^a + q(S-q^b).
$$
Solving this we find that ....
$$
S = \frac{q^a-q^{b+1}}{1-q}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
$$
\sum_{n = a}^{b} q^{n} = \sum_{n = 0}^{b} q^{n} - \sum_{n = 0}^{a-1} q^{n}.
$$
Now, if $M$ is either $a-1$ or $b$, and if $q<1$ then
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{M} q^{n} = {1 - q^{M+1} \over 1 - q}
$$
The last formula is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

And if $q=1$, then $q^{n} = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: $q$ cannot be 1.

Comment: The OP says, $0 \leq q \leq 1$.  And, I hope your nickname is commensurate with your actual publication record.

Comment: The OP ignores the existence of the Geometric Series, hence it ignores the radius of convergence of the same. Which means that you shall have told him that the series diverge for $q = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

First we assume $a \le b$ (otherwise we swap). With
$$
S = \sum_{k=a}^b q^k
$$
If $q=1$ we have $S=b - a + 1$. For $q < 1$
we have
$$
q S 
= \sum_{k=a}^b q^{k+1}
= \sum_{k=a+1}^{b+1} q^k
= S + q^{b+1} - q^a \iff \\
q^a - q^{b+1} = (1-q) S
$$
This gives
$$
S =
\begin{cases}
b - a + 1 & \text{ for } q = 1 \\
(q^a-q^{b+1})/(1-q) & \text{ for }  q < 1
\end{cases}
$$